# Get all innerhtml contents of span tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the content of all span tags that are children of div#parent and I am not able to do it, I just get the first one. Could someone help me, please!

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var allspans=$("#parent").find("span").html();
    console.log( allspans );
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>jQuery</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="parent">
    <span>Element_1</span>
    <span>Element_2</span>
    <span>Element_3</span>
    <span>Element_4</span>
    <span>Element_5</span>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!
Best Regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) and [`get()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjA6OHmgszVAhUBLI8KHaVyBLoQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fjquery.get%2F&usg=AFQjCNG6x37uSfL8iaFzQ94pXJ3pWBqjyA) function .You will get the all the span tag innerHTML with in array

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var allspans=$("#parent").find("span").map(function(){
    return $(this).html();
    }).get()
    console.log( allspans );
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>jQuery</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="parent">
    <span>Element_1</span>
    <span>Element_2</span>
    <span>Element_3</span>
    <span>Element_4</span>
    <span>Element_5</span>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the `span`'s using `.each`, and then access their individual `innerHTML`'s like this. Through the `.each` you can then combine the inner HTML content in an array or string.

Or, you could get the inner text of all `span`'s by `$("#parent").text()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#parent").find("span").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).html());
  });
  
  console.log($("#parent").text());
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>jQuery</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="parent">
    <span>Element_1</span>
    <span>Element_2</span>
    <span>Element_3</span>
    <span>Element_4</span>
    <span>Element_5</span>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

JQuery is slow and unnecessary for that.

```
spans = document.getElementById("parent").getElementsByTagName("span");
```

returns an array of all spans in parent.

**At this point the task is complete**, as I could understand it: **spans[span_number].innerHTML** is what you want.

Then just parse that spans array in any way (foreach or whatever you like):

```
for(var i = 0, len = spans.length; i < len; i++ )
{
    console.log(spans[i].innerHTML);
}
```

Avoid JQuery in any means (when possible) to make your code more independent, fast, less resource-intensive and robust. Save traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some loop until $("#parent").find("span").length, by default jquery html function will returns the first matched element content:

```
var html = '';
var allspans = $("#parent").find("span");
for(var i=0;i<allspans.length;i++){
  html += allspans[i].innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var allspans=$("#parent").find("span");
    var allSpanHtml = '';
    allspans.each(function() {
     allSpanHtml += $(this).html();
    });
    console.log( allSpanHtml );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
    <span>Element_1</span>
    <span>Element_2</span>
    <span>Element_3</span>
    <span>Element_4</span>
    <span>Element_5</span>
</div>
```

You can use [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate through an array of element, and then use [.html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/) to get text from individual element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var arraySpan = [];
$('span').each(function() {
   arraySpan.push(this.innerHTML);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to loop through each span matched by the selector and console log each html value or concatenate them into a variable or push them to an array variable; depending on whatever works best.

Do something like:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#parent").find("span").each(function(){
     console.log( $(this).html() );
    });
});
```

to log the html value of each span.